# Can python tell me which attributes of a class were defined in the current block?

Tags: python

For instance, the class declaration:

```
class Something(Superclass):
    an_attribute = 1
    another_attribute = 'hello'
```

Is there any way that python can tell me that `an_attribute` and `another_attribute` were defined in this class declaration?

Another way of framing this question, I guess, is "can I filter `dir` results by the class in which they were declared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attributes of a class are kept in it's special `__dict__` field. The `__dict__` contains only the attributes defined for the current class (as well as the special attributes). As others mentioned, it can be accessed either directly or via built-in `vars()` function.

I strongly recommend reading [this](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#the-dynamic-dict) article which explains how Python handles attributes in-depth.

Answer (score 4):

**Python 2.7**:

```
class A:
    var1 = 2
    va2 = 2
class B(A):
    var3 = 3
    var4 = 4

print(A.__dict__.keys()) #prints ['va2', '__module__', 'var1', '__doc__']
print(B.__dict__.keys()) #prints ['var4', '__module__', '__doc__', 'var3']
```

**Python 3:**

```
print(list(A.__dict__)) #prints ['__module__', 'var1', '__dict__', 'va2', '__weakref__', '__doc__']
print(list(B.__dict__)) #prints ['var4', '__module__', '__doc__', 'var3']
```

Comment: @BasicWolf There's  a edit button below every post, and SO is a collaborative site so you could have used that to edit my post, instead of downvoting it. :(

Comment: With this reasoning, we wouldn't need the downvote button at all – we could *always* fix the errors instead.  However, it's ridiculous to downvote because of stylistic preferences.  +1 from me.

Comment: Can we save the complaints about indentation level until SO has a decent code editor. +1 from me

Comment: Guys, this is my personal opinion, but check Ashwini Chaundhary's other answers @StackOverflow. 2 chars indent. Now, consider yourself some day reading that kind of code, and having no fancy IDE to re-indent it. Does it feel comfortable? The standards and particularly PEP8 were created for a sake of each one of us, it is also a part of what makes Python code readable. P.S. Ashwini Chaudhary, I see you haven't read PEP8 yet, because the code lines are longer than 80 characters :)

Comment: A minor improvement -- to print a list of keys in Python 3, instead of calling `keys()`, you could just do this: `print(list(A.__dict__))`.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary of attributes of the class `SomeThing` can be accessed by `vars(SomeThing)`.  See also the [documentation of `vars()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class Something(list):
...     an_attribute = 1
...     another_attribute = 'hello'
... 
>>> print vars(Something) == Something.__dict__
True
>>> 
>>> print vars(Something)
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'an_attribute': 1, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Something' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Something' objects>, 'another_attribute': 'hello'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is with [introspection](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html), using the example by @AshwiniChaudhary:

```
import inspect

class A:
    var1 = 2
    var2 = 2

class B(A):
    var3 = 3
    var4 = 4

[member for member in inspect.getmembers(B) if member not in inspect.getmembers(A)]
#prints [('var3', 3), ('var4', 4)]
```

With this approach you can decide from which class in the inheritance hierarchy you want to "subtract" the members, for example:

```
class One:
    #members

class Two:
    #members

...

class N:
    #members

[member for member in inspect.getmembers(N) if member not in inspect.getmembers(NMinusK)]
```

Answer (score -2):

There is builtin *hasattr* function

```
hasattr(object, name)
```

The result is True if the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, False if not. (This is implemented by calling *getattr(object, name)* and seeing whether it raises an exception or not.)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question at all. Specifically, given a class `Foo` and its subclass `Bar`, `hasattr(Bar, attr)` will return true whether the attribute is defined in `Foo` or `Bar`.