# Can I get all attributes that were defined in the __init__ method of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes, introspection

Suppose I have a class like this:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
        self.b = "b"
```

How would I get a dictionary like this ?

```py
{"a": "a", "b": "b"}
```

I read [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285599/can-python-tell-me-which-attributes-of-a-class-were-defined-in-the-current-block), but the dictionary in these answers always contains some "dunder" attributes as well, which *I never defined in `A.__init__`*. Will I have to use one of the solutions in the linked question and filter out the dunder attributes, or is there a smarter way ?

Comment: So, what do you get if you run for example `vars(A())`? I get what you want to have.

Comment: @KlausD. OMG i'm dumb - I tried this instead `vars(A)` which gave the output in my question …

Comment: `vars` really just returns `A().__dict__`.

Comment: Hard to tell if this question is an _exact_ duplicate or not without specifying whether the attributes defined in `__init__` only should be returned, or any one set at any point after. The duplicate solves the question as answered, but the title remains open IMO.

Comment: @TankorSmash `"whether the attributes defined in __init__ only should be returned"` - exactly, I want only these.

Comment: But there's nothing inherently special about the `__init__`-set attributes, compared to ones you add after. like `my_ad = A()`, then later you do `my_a.new_attr = 'some val'` outside of `__init__`, you still want to see `new_attr` in the dict, right?

Comment: @TankorSmash no I don't want to see these, but I won't with the accepted solution, because I do `self.attrs = vars(A())` at the end of the `__init__` method !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by looking at the `__dict__` attribute or using the `vars` function like so:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
        self.b = "b"

print(A().__dict__)  # prints {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
print(vars(A()))     # also prints {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
```

Comment: In fact, given `a = A()`, `a.__dict__ is vars(a)` should be true.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A:
    foo = 'bar'

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
        self.b = "b"

a = A()
print(vars(a)) # prints "{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}"
print({k: v for k, v in vars(A).items() if not k.startswith('__')}) # prints "{'foo': 'bar'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm not understanding your question, but the easiest method for getting a dictionary of attributes like you described is as follows:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "A"
        self.b = "B"

x = A()

print(x.__dict__)
```

This should give you:

```
{a: "A", b: "B"}
```

The dict attribute is a dunder attribute, but it is the most elegant solution for this IMO. Is there a specific reason you'd like to avoid this method? If not, I recommend it for simplicity's sake.